# How to printf argument in a script adding

Tags: bash, printf

I am writing a script that run other scripts. Two argument are parsing to this script. The script create a directory and copy scripts from a archive to the created folder. One of the scripts is a .config file with constants variables but I want to write the two arguments because they will be variables I will need later.

I can do with this

```
printf "FASTAQ1 = ${FASTA1}"  >> $DIRECTORY/$FASTA1/scripts/shortcut.config
```

But the results is

```
FASTAQ1 = fasta1.fasta
```

But I think that what I need is this

```
FASTAQ1 = "fasta1.fasta"
```

Am I right? If so, How can I add theses quotation marks?

Comment: I have tried that and I think I tried this before asking the question here but the results is exactly the same I put in the question.

Comment: Sorry I meant: `printf 'FASTAQ1 = "%s"\n' "$FASTA1" >> "$DIRECTORY/$FASTA1/scripts/shortcut.config"`

Comment: Ahh I see what was our mistake I made exactly the same error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To print a quotation mark with printf, you can escape it with a backslash.

So, if you want to write the string `FASTAQ1 = "fasta1.fasta"` into a file at  $DIRECTORY/$FASTA1/scripts/shortcut.config, given an environment variable FASTA1="fast1.fasta", you could do something like (ref. my bash terminal log):

```
FASTA1=fasta1.fasta
DIRECTORY=`pwd`
mkdir -p $DIRECTORY/$FASTA1/scripts
printf "FASTAQ1 = \"${FASTA1}\"" >> $DIRECTORY/$FASTA1/scripts/shortcut.config
```

Producing a shortcut.config with this contents:
`FASTAQ1 = "fasta1.fasta"`

Comment: In general you would normally use `printf` instead of `echo`, because `echo` is not portable. For details see here: https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/echo+printf/

Comment: Jeez.. This makes me embarrassed. I must learn, redo, and come up with a better answer, then.

Comment: Why `$DIRECTORY`?! What’s its function? Relative paths would work just fine. Also, this code has some smell, see what [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) has to say about it.

Comment: I agree the `$DIRECTORY` isn't needed. But it was part of the quesiton, so I think one should give an answer to it. Thanks for the shellcheck tip!